# Open File in vscode using postCreateCommand in devcontainer.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

My devcontainer requires a configuration file from a mounted volume. If that file doesn't exist after creating the container, I want to create a new one and open it in vscode for the user to provide the content.

I used

```
"postCreateCommand": "test ! -f /root/.config/openstack/clouds.yaml && (mkdir -p /root/.config/openstack; code --wait /root/.config/openstack/clouds.yaml)",
```

but it complains about `code or code-insiders is not installed`.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: I have the same issue trying to show a readme file to the user when the container is started. Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @Steven Sadly, I didn't. I even opened an issue with them to clarify. Response: "The backchannel is only available in the integrated terminal". It's now a feature-request, which is unlikely to end up in the backlog.

Comment: Thanks, now I know not to waste my time on it. I settled for echo-ing instructions in a `postStartCommand` which is always displayed in the integrated terminal when the dev container is started. Perhaps it's possible to add font colors if it turns out people still don't read it.